# PCC V10 import lines

Tags: csv, pervasive

PCC V10-have exported the table (MS Excel), identified which transactions are missing and have isolated them in same format as original file.
Have saved as `.csv` with and without headers - wont' import.

I have saved as `.txt` file, says it imported the lines successfully, but I can find them? any suggestions as to the correct import procedure from csv format into pcc (open item file) table

Comment: Sounds like you are doing the right steps to import the data.  How are you looking for them when you can't find them?  How do you know they aren't there? Make sure you're using the latest version of V10.  It went unsupported in March 2012 but you can still download updates at http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv10.aspx.

Comment: Morning, Thank You - sorry, found the lines but they were blank. Thank you for your feedback, found my mistake too.